# Transpose variables to observations in SAS base

Tags: sas, transpose

I think this isnt the most advanced question but i cannot seem to make it work in SAS. I have the following variables: ID, conc (concentration), T0, T1, T2, T3 (times)

```
ID  Conc    T0     T1     T2     T3
1   Text    10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00
1   3000
1   2000
1   1500
1   1000
2   Text    10:01  11:02  12:03  13:04
2   3000
2   2000
2   1500
2   1000
```

To

```
ID  Conc    Time     
1   Text      
1   3000    10:00
1   2000    11:00
1   1500    12:00
1   1000    13:00
2   Text      
2   3000    10:01
2   2000    11:02
2   1500    12:03
2   1000    13:04
```

I have tried proc transpose, but i cannot seem to transform the data correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want that extra observation where CONC='Text' in the output?  What purpose does it serve in the output dataset?

Comment: Wouldn't have been easier to create the daaset in the style you want to start with? What was the source of the original data?  If it was a simple text file then you could probably read it into the structure you want while reading the text file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to transpose from wide to tall is by using an ARRAY. That method would work well for this problem.

One way to get the times carried forward onto each row is to use the UPDATE statement.  Use the same dataset as both the original and transaction dataset by using OBS=0 dataset option to start from an empty original dataset.  Add an explicit OUTPUT statement so that all observations are  written rather than just one per ID group.

Create a row counter variable by using SUM statement which you can use to index into the array.

```
data want;
  update have(obs=0) have;
  by id;
  if first.id then row=0;
  else row+1;
  array times t0-t3 ;
  if 1<=row<=dim(times) then time=times[row];
  output;
  format time time5.;
  drop t0-t3;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    ID    Conc    row     time

  1     1    Text     0         .
  2     1    3000     1     10:00
  3     1    2000     2     11:00
  4     1    1500     3     12:00
  5     1    1000     4     13:00
  6     2    Text     0         .
  7     2    3000     1     10:01
  8     2    2000     2     11:02
  9     2    1500     3     12:03
 10     2    1000     4     13:04
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this program, but i end up with the following results:

Obs    ID    Conc    row     time

  1     1    Text          0        .
  2     1    3000         1       .
  3     1    2000         2       .
  4     1    1500         3       .
  5     1    1000         4       . 
  6     2    Text          0        .
  7     2    3000         1        .
  8     2    2000         2       .
  9     2    1500         3       .
 10    2    1000         4       .
What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: No idea.  Post a new question or update your original question.  Show the data you used,  the code you ran, and explain in what way it does not produce what you want.